# How to customize WooCommerce product sorting by attributes?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I tried the code below but it doesn't work.

I add in the category link:

/?orderby=pa_diametru-exterior

No products were found matching your selection.

Can you help me make it work.

Thank you

```
/************* Add sorting by attributes **************/

/**
 * Defines the criteria for sorting with options defined in the method below
 */
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args');

function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
    global $wp_query;
    // Changed the $_SESSION to $_GET
    if (isset($_GET['orderby'])) {
        switch ($_GET['orderby']) :
            case 'pa_diametru-exterior' :
                $args['order'] = 'ASC';
                $args['meta_key'] = 'pa_diametru-exterior';
                $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
                break;
        endswitch;
    }
    return $args;
}

/**
 * Adds the sorting options to dropdown list .. The logic/criteria is in the method above
 */
add_filter('woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby');

function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {
    $sortby['pa_diametru-exterior'] = 'pa_diametru-exterior';
    return $sortby;
}

/**
 * Save custom attributes as post's meta data as well so that we can use in sorting and searching
 */
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_woocommerce_attr_to_meta' );
function save_woocommerce_attr_to_meta( $post_id ) {
    // Get the attribute_names .. For each element get the index and the name of the attribute
    // Then use the index to get the corresponding submitted value from the attribute_values array.
    foreach( $_REQUEST['diametru-exterior'] as $index => $value ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, $value, $_REQUEST['attribute_values'][$index] );
    }
}
/************ End of Sorting ***************************/
```